# Upload the image in HTML and get the image path

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I used `<input type="file" accept="image/*">` to upload the image and base64 encoding of the image in the onload callback function of the FileReader instance, which was successful. But when I assign this base64 encoding to another data variable, it fails, and I can't get its value. Why is that? Could you help me? Thank you!

```
<div id="app">
  <input type="file" accept="image/*" @change="changeFile" ref="file">  
  <img :src="imgUrl" ref="image">
  <div :style="{background: 'url(' + imgUrl + ')'}"></div>
  <p>{{imgUrl}}</p>
</div>

var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    imgUrl: ''
  },
  methods: {
    changeFile() {
      let reader = new FileReader();
      let file = this.$refs.file;
      let image = this.$refs.image;
      reader.readAsDataURL(file.files[0]);
      reader.onload = function(e) {
        let temp = this.result;
        this.imgUrl = temp;
        image.src = temp;
      }
    }
  }
})
```

[image]

Comment: You want to use your base64 data somewhere else?

Comment: Yes, I also want to use this base64 data as a background image. @Sebastian Waldbauer

Comment: Your [posted](https://jsfiddle.net/OskarSniper/qh8zvuL3/4/) code is working. You can access your variable temp and use a function to send it somewhere.

Comment: Yes, the```<img>``` works, but the ```<div>```doesn't show the background image, and the ```<p>``` doesn't show base64 data. If you look at elements, you will see that they are not getting base64 data. As the picture above shows.@Sebastian Waldbauer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because of `this` the bad boy in JS world:

```
<div id="app">
  <input type="file" accept="image/*" @change="changeFile" ref="file">  
  <img :src="imgUrl" ref="image">
  <div :style="{background: 'url(' + imgUrl + ')'}"></div>
  <p>{{imgUrl}}</p>
</div>

var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    imgUrl: ''
  },
  methods: {
    changeFile() {
      let reader = new FileReader();
      let file = this.$refs.file;
      let image = this.$refs.image;

      // keep the "this" for later use:
      let thisComp = this;

      reader.readAsDataURL(file.files[0]);
      reader.onload = function(e) {
        let temp = this.result;
        thisComp.imgUrl = temp;
        image.src = temp;
      }
    }
  }
})
```

In your case `this` referred to the caller of the function that `this` has been used in (here it's the `FileReader` object `reader`), that's why the data `imgUrl` was not changed at all.